# What does "=>" operator mean in a property in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

What does this code mean?

```
public bool property => method();
```

Comment: Maybe you should search for lambda operator

Comment: @meJustAndrew that's not a lambda operator. It's an expression bodied member, a *new* language feature

Comment: Search for "expression bodied properties".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [Actually is is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, is to specify the return of an only get property, C#6 stuff

Comment: @DavidG the OP is asking about expression bodied properties, not lambdas. Looking for lambdas is *not* going to return helpful results. You can't use the lambda operator this way in C#5

Comment: @Liam definitely not. The OP is asking about expression-bodied properties, not lambdas.

Comment: You should take a look at the new language features: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You’ve commented on two (now-deleted) answers telling them not to link to duplicates. Please be aware that these answers didn’t link to duplicate questions but (completely correctly) to the relevant documentation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the answerer himself in one of those questions pointed out that link-only questions aren't good even when they point to SO documentation. The other answer was wrong, confusing expression-bodied members for lambdas

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but link-only is unrelated to the fact that links to documentation are not the same as links to duplicate questions. I’m not contesting that these answers were deleted, I just wanted to make you aware of Stack Overflow’s documentation section. Regarding the correctness of the second answer, the Roslyn announcement itself calls expression-bodied functions “lambda expressions” which I find confusing but well.

Comment: Asking and answering such question once a year seems to bring a lot of attention.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is an *expression-bodied property*, a new syntax for computed properties introduced in C# 6, which lets you create computed properties in the same way as you would create a lambda expression. This syntax is equivalent to

```
public bool property {
    get {
        return method();
    }
}
```

Similar syntax works for methods, too:

```
public int TwoTimes(int number) => 2 * number;
```

Comment: The correct (ie googlable) name is "expression-bodied property"

Comment: The only explanation in the answers.

Comment: First time I've seen, this my first reaction to it is, *why?*. At no point have I ever looked at the property and gone, *you know what that needs, an arbitrary lambda type syntax*... Maybe a slow day at Redmond

Comment: The [MSDN Blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) seems to agree *There’s nothing particularly radical about expression bodied functions* <thumbsup>

Comment: @Liam I have been using this feature for a few months now. It is particularly good for wrapper classes with lots of delegation, but it occasionally helps with a property or two in a regular class.

Comment: Got my vote for teaching me it can be used in methods.

Comment: @Liam When you have computable properties, for example a `Vector` class, where most operations and properties are a simple mathematical formula, which fit in one line. For example, you could have a `public Vector Normalized => this / this.Length;` property, which looks much better than all the nested braces.

Comment: @Liam IMHO C# has a whitespace problem, i.e. way too many lines with, say, one curly brace. Making some constructs more compact improves readability, at least for me.

Answer (score 19):

As some mentioned this is a new feature brought first to C# 6, they extended its usage in [C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) to use it with getters and setters, you can also use the expression bodied syntax with methods like this:

```
static bool TheUgly(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
static bool TheNormal(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}
static bool TheShort(int a, int b) => a > b; //beautiful, isn't it?
```

Answer (score 11):

That's an expression bodied property. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) for example.
This is just a shorthand for

```
public bool property
{
    get
    {
        return method();
    }
}
```

Expression bodied functions are also possible:

```
public override string ToString() => string.Format("{0}, {1}", First, Second);
```

Answer (score 6):

`=>` used in property is an `expression body`. Basically a shorter and cleaner way to write a property with only `getter`.

```
public bool MyProperty {
     get{
         return myMethod();
     }
}
```

Is translated to

```
public bool MyProperty => myMethod();
```

It's much more simpler and readable but you can only use this operator from C# 6 and [here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-expression-bodied-method.html) you will find specific documentation about expression body.

Answer (score 3):

It's the expression bodied simplification.

```
public string Text =>
  $"{TimeStamp}: {Process} - {Config} ({User})";
```

Reference; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Answer (score -3):

That is a expression bodied property. It can be used as a simplification from property getters or method declarations.
From C# 7 it was also expanded to other member types like constructors, finalizers, property setters and indexers.

Check the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) documentation for more info.

"Expression body definitions let you provide a member's implementation in a very concise, readable form. You can use an expression body definition whenever the logic for any supported member, such as a method or property, consists of a single expression."

Comment: No it is not. It is an expression-bodied member

Comment: This answer shouldn't be downvoted as a *lot* of people don't know about expression bodied members. Including some of the downvoters I'd guess. That doesn't make this a bad answer. In C# 5 this would be a *correct* answer. It should be deleted though to remove the negative rep