# C# 6.0 => Operator

Tags: c#

I'm using visual studio 2013. I found a project in github, that project is using Visual Studio 2015. I'm trying to compile it but I get an error using vs2013

> Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Here code's :

```
private readonly Log _log;
public Log Log => _log; // What => Operator is doing ? Pointer ?
```

Yes, What new features of `=>` operator in `C# [6.0]`? and is there any way to use C# 6.0 in vs2013?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: No, upgrade your VS version.

Comment: C# 6.0 was introduced with VS 2015. There is no way to use it in VS 2013. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-property-like-function-members

Comment: Or replace it by `public Log Log { get; private set; }`.

Comment: c# 6 has been introduced with Visual Studio 2015 so you only can use the body expression in VS 15 or later version

Comment: I like how [two questions about that operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282424/what-does-operator-mean-in-a-property-in-c) are asked the same day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expression-bodied property, a new syntax for computed properties introduced in C# 6, which lets you create computed properties in the same way as you would create a lambda expression. So:

```
public int TwoTimes(int number)
{
    return 2*number;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public int TwoTimes(int number) => 2 * number;
```

**Note**: C# 6.0 was introduced with VS 2015. You can not use it with an earlier version.

**Ref**: [What does "=>" operator mean in a property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282424/what-does-operator-mean-in-a-property-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

It is a shorter version to write a readonly property.

```
public Log Log => _log;
```

equals

```
public Log Log { get { return _log; } }
```

But I know of no way to use this feature in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Visual Studio 2013 doesnt support C# 6.0.
Convert it in an older way, like in answer before

```
private readonly Log _log;
public Log Log 
{
    get { return _log; }
}
```