# Add item to existing Collection C#

Tags: c#, collections

I have Collection:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public double Index { set; get; }
        public double A { set; get; }
        public double B { set; get; }
        public double C { set; get; }
    }
    List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
```

I filled A and B with some random numbers. After that, I want add items C in collection. For example, what I trying:

```
        foreach (Test t in test)
        {
            c = t.A + t.B;
            test.Add(new Test {C = c }); <------ 
        }
```

How can I add element C on same position like A and B? (Sorry for my english)

Comment: The "items" of the collection already have a `C` property, as such it seems what you want to do is this: `foreach (Test t in test) { t.C = t.A + t.B; }`, can you verify if this is what you want?

Comment: Only one element can be in one position. You can Insert(index, item) instead od Adding, though.

Comment: Just saying (as I don't really get what you are trying to do anyway so it might be something to consider for you)... `public double C { get { return A + B; } }`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  Yes it is ... It was simple, lol ... Sometimes I thinking very hard way... Thank you very much

Comment: Please take a look at the answer that has been posted, it may be that that is an even better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Test t in test)
{
    t.C = t.A + t.B;
}
```

just set the property to the equation

Answer (score 3):

If you want `C` to be the sum of `A` and `B` it might be better to use a computed field:

```
public class Test
{
    public double Index { set; get; }
    public double A { set; get; }
    public double B { set; get; }
    public double C 
    { 
       get
       {
            return A + B;
       } 
    }
}
```

So

```
Test test = new Test()
{
   A = 1;
   B = 2;
};

test.C == 3; //true
```

the advantage of the above is that `C` is always the sum of the other values and you don't need to recompute it every time. So if I take above and do:

```
test.B = 3; //instead of the original 2
```

Then `C` stays in sync:

```
test.C == 3; //false
test.C == 4; //now true
```

To do this with your original method (or the other answer) means re-looping the result set.

Or in C# 6.0 you can use an [expression-bodied property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282424/what-does-operator-mean-in-a-property-in-c)

```
public class Test
{
    public double Index { set; get; }
    public double A { set; get; }
    public double B { set; get; }
    public double C =>  A + B;
}
```