# Xamarin command data binding works if => operator used but does not work if = operator used

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have simple Xamarin forms(5.0.0.2012) application. It contains a XAML page and a corresponding view model.

I have the following SearchBar element in the XAML file:

```
    <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Placeholder="Search vacancies..."
               SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearchCommand}" 
               SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}"/>
```

I have the following public Command property and static method in the view model:

```
public class SearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand PerformSearchCommand => new Command(PerformSearch);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static void PerformSearch()
    {
        var i = 10;
        i++;
    }
```

When the search icon is clicked in the SearchBar. The PerformSearch() method is executed as expected. However, if I change the code to the following, the PerformSearch() method is no longer called.

```
public class SearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand PerformSearchCommand = new Command(PerformSearch);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static void PerformSearch()
    {
        var i = 10;
        i++;
    }
```

I need to be able to use '=' approach to initialise the command in the constructor to pass in a non static method to execute. I have tested this issue on an android emulator.
Is this a Xamarin bug?

Comment: A private method is not visible publicly, therefore, it makes no sense to have a static method that is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Command needs to be a property in order to be able to bind it. The first line is a property because:

```
public ICommand PerformSearchCommand => new Command(PerformSearch);
```

is equivalent to

```
public ICommand PerformSearchCommand { get { return new Command(PerformSearch); }
```

The second one is a field not a property

```
 public ICommand PerformSearchCommand = new Command(PerformSearch);
```

#### Related questions

[What is the => assignment in C# in a property signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31764532)

[What does "=>" operator mean in a property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40282424)

[What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104)

#### Related documentations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: Thank you. I understand now and the code is fixed!

Comment: I tried upvoting but do not have enough reputation. Didn't realise there was an accept action. Done now!

Comment: Thanks no issue, try to take time to read the official documentation properly it is very helpful